# Unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW on ternary if operator

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem on setting an array index using a ternary if operator. What I'm trying to do is, if a statement satisfies an if condition, I want to add an additional index to an array which I will be using to insert data from the database. However, every time I use the ternary if operator to include these array indices, I always get an error

> Unexpected '=>' T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Here is my code:

```
$data = array('remark' => $this->input->post('remark'),
           'rating' => $this->input->post('rating'),
           ($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'Customer' ? 'user_id' => $_SESSION['id'] : ''),
           ($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'Customer' ? 'food_item_id' => $this->input->post['refid'] : ''));
```

Anyone who knows how to solve this problem? Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @Qirel already tried the solutions mentioned in the page but the problem still persists

Comment: Because the double arrow is inside the ternary operator. This isn't how you add elements to the array dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You can't selectively set indexes while defining an array (the way you are) but you can use array_filter to remove the unwanted indexes for you:

```
$data = array_filter(array(
    'remark' => $this->input->post('remark'),
    'rating' => $this->input->post('rating'),
    'user_id' => $_SESSION['user_type'] == 'Customer' ? $_SESSION['id'] : '',
    'food_item_id' => $_SESSION['user_type'] == 'Customer' ? $this->input->post['refid'] : '',
));
```

This way any empty string values in the array will be removed before being assigned to the $data variable.

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way you should use it:

```
$data = array('remark' => $this->input->post('remark'),
           'rating' => $this->input->post('rating'),
           'user_id' => ($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'Customer' ?  $_SESSION['id'] : ''),
           'food_item_id' => ($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'Customer' ?  $this->input->post['refid'] : ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the ternary if functionality to after the `=>` like so

```
$data = array(
            'remark'        => $this->input->post('remark'),
            'rating'        => $this->input->post('rating'),
            'user_id'       => $_SESSION['user_type'] == 'Customer' 
                            ? $_SESSION['user_type'] 
                            : '',
            'food_item_id'  => $_SESSION['user_type'] == 'Customer' 
                            ? $this->input->post['refid'] 
                            : ''
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add data dynamically to an array, you shouldn't do it with ternary operators like that if you don't want the key to exist if the condition fails. Add them separately by checking on the condition *after* defining the array and add the elements if the condition is true.

```
$data = array('remark' => $this->input->post('remark'),
              'rating' => $this->input->post('rating'));

if ($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'Customer')
    $data['user_id'] = $_SESSION['id'];
if ($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'Customer')
    $data['food_item_id'] = $this->input->post['refid'];
```

You can still use a ternary operator inside the array-definition, but then you would still create the keys (even though the value in that element is empty)

```
$data = array('remark' => $this->input->post('remark'),
              'rating' => $this->input->post('rating'),
              'user_id' => ($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'Customer' ? $_SESSION['id'] : ''),
              'food_item_id' => ($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'Customer' ? $this->input->post['refid'] : ''));
```

Comment: I also tried to work with that solution, but I was shown an `Unknown field type` error when I'm already trying to insert the data on the database

Comment: If you need the keys to exist in the array (wasn't specified in the question), then you need the second snippet of code.

Comment: I'm referring to the second snippet of code where I'm receiving an `Unknown field type` error

Comment: Though its not related to the question you originally asked (your question was answered 3 times), that sounds like it might either be an issue that `$this->input->post['refid']` should be `$this->input->post('refid')`, or an issue in some part of the code you haven't shown. Either way, the original question you asked has been answered, and you should accept one answer here, and ask a new question for that - because it's a different question :-)